# How to Find if word-wrap is applied to a html element, and that word breaked in middle of text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text in Persain inside a `div` which is wrapped because I've applied
`word-wrap: break-word;` and the div is smaller than the text.

```
<div class="r25" style="width: 13.3333px; height: 50px;">
    <p style="font-size: 8px;">نمونه‌ای از یک متن بلند</p>
</div>
```

My question is how I can find out if word-wrap: break-word;` has been applied?

The text `نمونه‌ای از یک متن بلند` is rendered like this:

`نم‌‌‌
ونه
‌ای`

and so on.

Those `width`, `height` and `font-size` styles are generated using a script and 
if this `breaking word in middle of a word, not whole word` has happened to my text, I want to apply some transform.

**EDIT:**

I have a solution in mind: iterate over each word, get the text width, and compare it to the `div`'s width. But could there be any simpler solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the text including the formatting inside a `div`:

```
var $div = $("#mydiv");
var expectedDiv = $("<div>" +$div.html()+"</div>");
$div.after(expectedDiv);
```

then get the height of this `div` and remove it:

```
var expectedHeight = expectedDiv.height();
expectedDiv.remove();
```

Now you can calculate the line count:

```
var linecount = Math.floor($div.height() / expectedHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsqvmf8t/

Answer (score -1):

You can find using **Browser Inspector**

Comment: it is inside a script that those styles are applied, and i want to found it inside script

Comment: ahmad, can you provide that script, and applied styles by scripts are also apear in browser inspactor like this: `element.style {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}`